# Uploading Profile Picture to ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add an image to my user model.

```
namespace GoldTeamProject7.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
....
}
```

I would like to be able to upload the photo on registration.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Zipcode = model.Zipcode, ProfileImage = model.ProfileImage };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ImageFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    ApplicationUser.ProfileImage = ms.ToArray();
                }
```

And in the view I have

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProfileImage)
</div>

<input name="Image" type="file" />
<p>
    <input name="ImageFile" type="file" />
</p>
```

The problem is I get an error here

```
 ApplicationUser.ProfileImage = ms.ToArray();
```

I get an error that says

> "Error    24  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'GoldTeamProject7.Models.ApplicationUser.ProfileImage.get'    C:\Users\sethj_000\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\GoldTeamProject7\GoldTeamProject7\Controllers\AccountController.cs  161 21  GoldTeamProject7"

I added the property to the model, added the property to the view model, added the code to write it to the Db in the controller, but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting that object error reference. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It should be`user.ProfileImage = ms.ToArray();` and put `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);` line below `using`

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I needed to add that data to the object created by the ApplicationUser class. I get it now. Thank you so much